# synchronized between the main thread of android and another thread

Tags: java, android

Android by design doesn't allow network on the main thread it can be forced but its not a good practice. So I want to synchronized the main thread and one other thread so I can get the response from the database for user authentication. My synchronization is not working..

This is the code in the main thread..

```
if (loginBTN.getId() == ((Button) v).getId()) {

    String emailId = loginField.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = passwordField.getText().toString().trim();

    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", emailId));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    try {

        System.out.println("b4 response" + responseToString);

        checkLogin();

        System.out.println("after response" + responseToString);

        synchronized (this) {

            while (isAvailable == false) {

                wait();

            }

            if (responseToString.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

                statusLBL.setText("Login Successful...");

            }

            else {

                statusLBL.setText("Sorry Incorrect Username or Password...");

            }
        }

    }

    catch (Exception e) {

        statusLBL.setText(e.toString());
    }

}




private void checkLogin() {

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    HttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://example.org/api/android_gradhub/login_user.php");
                    UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
                    request.setEntity(formEntity);
                    HttpResponse response = http.execute(request);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    // responseToString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                    synchronized (this) {

                        while (isAvailable == true) {

                            wait();

                        }

                        responseToString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                        notifyAll();
                    }

                    System.out.println("response " + responseToString);
                }

                catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();

    }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The synchronization is not working..

Answer (score 0):

Remove all of your synhronization and then just put `thread.join()` as the last statement in `checkLogin`. **This is the simplest way to wait for the thread to complete before proceeding.**

If you want to decide when to wait (like you might want to do other stuff in the main program before the login needs to be checked) then you can **return the thread** from `checkLogin`. Than you decide when to `join` back in your main program. (i.e. signature changes to `public Thread checkLogin` and last line of checkLogin becomes `return thread`. Back in your main program, call `Thread thread = checkLogin();` when you want to wait for the checkLogin to finish - use `thread.join()`, up until that point Main thread and checkLogin thread is concurrent).

Comment: That worked but can help me fix my synchronization I am learning multi-threading so it would be a great help..

Comment: Why do you need synchronization in your example. What is the contentious resource? A more realistic example of a **shared resource** problem would help.

Comment: responseToString is contentious resource

Comment: Ok. Now the relationship between `responseToString` and `isAvailable` is not clear. Is there code that sets `isAvailable`?

Comment: yes If I have a response I store it in responseToString and isAvailable is true.. or otherwise it is false